# Doubt on a proof of continuity of a monotonically increasing function on an interval

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, continuity, solution-verification

Consider the following **statement**:
 Let $f:I \to R$ be an increasing function. Let $c\in I$ not be an endpoint of the interval $I$. Then prove that $f$ is continuous at $c \in I\; $ if and only if $\; \exists $ a sequence $(x_n) \subset I$ such that $x_{2n-1} \lt c \;\; \text{and} \; x_{2n} \gt c \;\forall n\in N; \text{and such that} \;x_n \to c \; \text{and}\; f(x_n)\to f(c)$ 
I have tried to prove the above statement as follows: 
 **To prove:** $f$ is continuous at $c \in I\; \text{(not an endpoint)} \iff \exists $ a sequence $(x_n) \subset I$ such that $x_{2n-1} \lt c \;\; \text{and} \; x_{2n} \gt c \;\forall n\in N; \text{and such that} \;x_n \to c \; \text{and}\; f(x_n)\to f(c)$  $(P \iff Q,  \text{say})$ 
 $P\Rightarrow Q$: trivial 
 $P \Leftarrow Q:$ 
If for $x\in I, x\lt c\;\text{then,}\\ f(x)\le f(c) \Rightarrow sup f(x)\le f(c)$ 
Since $f$ is increasing hence $\lim_{x\to c^-} f(x)= \sup(f(x): x<c)=\lim (x_{2n-1})=f(c) \; \text{(using sequential criteria for $\lim_{x\to c^-} f(x))$ and that $f(c)=\lim f(x_n))$} $ 
 Similarly, $\lim_{x\to c^+} f(x)=\inf(f(x): x>c)=\lim f(x_{2n})=f(c)$ 
Since, $\lim_{x\to c^-} f(x)=\lim_{x\to c^+} f(x)=f(c) \Rightarrow f \text { is continuous at c}$. Hence Proved. 
 
Is my proof correct? 
 I think it is wrong because it may so happen that the sequence $(x_n)$ defined in $(Q)$ does not exist however if for all the sequences $(y_n)$ which exist and converge to $c, f(y_n)$ also converges to $f(c)$, then by sequential criteria for continuity of a function, $f$ is continuous at $c$. 
My question is how do I prove that the existence of $(x_n)$ as defined in $Q$ above is sufficient for $f$ to be continuous at c? Please advice what I am missing here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why an image? It contains mostly text ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, edited it.

Comment: Frankly speaking your proof is not at all clear. All you say is that left limit of $f$ at $c$ does not exceed $f(c) $ (similar statement for right limit). But you don't show them equal.

Comment: The proof is much simpler than you think. And getting bogged down into symbols is a sure way to get confused. The left limit of $f$ equals $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_{2n-1})$ as $x_{2n-1}<c$ and $x_{2n-1}\to c$. Similarly right limit equals $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_{2n})$. Since $f(x_n) \to f(c) $ the above left right limits are equal to $f(c) $.

Comment: You should expand my comment into a full blown answer giving all the details (again without too much symbolism).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, Please relook. I have shown left limit to be equal to f(c) in the post. Besides, my doubt is: is Q sufficient for P to hold good?

Comment: Why do you bring $\inf, \sup$ here. Their usage is correct but they are not needed.

Comment: I also suspect a few typos. Do you want to write $\lim f(x_{2n})$ instead of $\lim (x_{2n})$ (see your post)? If that's the case then your approach is almost correct.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, correct. that's $lim f(x_{2n})$. I typed it erroneously. Thanks.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, Please relook.The equality of Left limit to f(c) is shown in the post.  $\lim_{x\to c^-} f(x)= \sup(f(x): x<c)=\lim (x_{2n-1})=f(c) \; $ [using sequential criteria for $\lim_{x\to c^-} f(x)$ and that $f(c)=\lim f(x_n)$].        
 Is there anything wrong with it?I used supremum because for increasing functions left limit equals supremum as I have mentioned in my post. But since for $f$ to be continuous at $c$, $f(y_n) \to f(c) $ for every sequence $y_n \to c$. Since in the question only one type of sequence was given. I tried to generalize.